# Subquery to SUM info not included in table result from JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, conditional-statements, aggregate

So I feel like this has probably been answered somewhere already, but I've scoured the internet all night and continue to come up empty handed. I have 3 tables in a MySQL database and I'm using a JOIN statement on them. I'm filtering the results by sport (i.e., only those with sport equal to NFL).

The problem is I want to create a column on the filtered results that sums the amount of times stats in other sports show up as well. But following the `WHERE Sport.type = 'NFL'` that becomes impossible because I've filtered out all those instances. I'm now thinking I need something along the lines of a subquery, but I'm not sure how to organize it so that I can draw query results that list each `player_id` only once and then allow me to tabulate columns of data referencing any information related to that `player_id` throughout the database, even if it's been filtered through the `JOIN` statement. I feel like this should be so easy and I'm just missing something.

Really simple code example is below. Can someone please help? Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT
  Player.player_id,
  Player.contact,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sport.type != 'NFL' THEN Info.Minutes ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    Player
JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
WHERE Sport.type = 'NFL'
GROUP BY Player.player_id);
```

Comment: Which table has `Minutes` column?

Comment: Hey Samir, thank you so much for your quick reply. Your answer worked, but the problem I'm having now is the same players are showing up on multiple rows when I want just one entry for each unique player value and columns going across representing different variables for that given player. `Minutes` column is in the `Info` table.

Comment: ok will update my post. If a player is in both NFL and non NFL game, then what is your expected stats? 0 or sum of `MINUTES`?

Comment: I am eventually creating separate columns for each instance. So there would basically be an `NFL_only` column and an `All_other_sports` column.

Comment: so if player is present in both the scenarios, you need 2 stats (2 columns), one will be 0 and other will sum of minutes. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: check my post with new query

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
SELECT
  Player.player_id,
  Player.contact,
  0 AS stats
FROM
    Player
JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
WHERE Sport.type = 'NFL'
GROUP BY Player.player_id

UNION

SELECT
  Player.player_id,
  Player.contact,
  SUM(Minutes) AS stats
FROM
    Player
JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
WHERE Sport.type != 'NFL'
GROUP BY Player.player_id;
```

**UPDATE**

To get unique players but different stats use below query.

> E.g.
>
> 1. If a player falls under both NFL and non NFL, it will return `NFL_only` as `1` and `All_other_sports` as `Sum of minutes`.
> 2. If a player falls under NFL only, it will return NFL_only`as`1`and`All_other_sports`as`0`.
> 3. If a player falls under Other sports only, it will return NFL_only`as`0`and`All_other_sports`as`Sum of minutes`.

```
SELECT z.player_id, z.contact, SUM(z.NFL_only) AS NFL_only, SUM(z.All_other_sports) AS All_other_sports
FROM (
    SELECT
      Player.player_id,
      Player.contact,
      1 AS NFL_only,
      0 AS All_other_sports
    FROM
    Player
    JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
    JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
    WHERE Sport.type = 'NFL'
    GROUP BY Player.player_id

    UNION

    SELECT
      Player.player_id,
      Player.contact,
      0 AS NFL_only,
      SUM(Minutes) AS All_other_sports
    FROM
    Player
    JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
    JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
    WHERE Sport.type != 'NFL'
    GROUP BY Player.player_id;
) z
GROUP BY z.player_id;
```

**Update 2**

As per your clear requirement, If one of my original tables has a column indicating the sport (i.e., NFL, MLB, NBA), what I want is a list of the players who have played NFL at least once. Then, if they've played the other sports I'd like to know how many times they've played them. The problem is if I filter only those rows with NFL I can no longer count the rows that had MLB and NBA because I've removed them with the JOIN.

```
SELECT
  Player.player_id,
  Player.contact,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sport.type != 'NFL' THEN Info.Minutes ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
  Player
JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
WHERE Player.player_id IN (
    SELECT
      Player.player_id,
    FROM
    Player
    JOIN Info ON Player.player_id = Info.player_id
    JOIN Sport ON Sport.game_id = Info.game_id
    WHERE Sport.type = 'NFL'
    GROUP BY Player.player_id
)
GROUP BY Player.player_id;
```

The subquery will return only NFL players. The main query will filter only NFL players and return expected output.

Comment: Hey Samir, I'm still having trouble. I'm thinking maybe a subquery is what I need? I probably haven't explained very well, but if one of my original tables has a column indicating the sport (i.e., NFL, MLB, NBA), what I want is a list of the players who have played NFL at least once. Then, if they've played the other sports I'd like to know how many times they've played them. The problem is if I filter only those rows with NFL I can no longer count the rows that had MLB and NBA because I've removed them with the `JOIN`. Does that make sense?